# J3.8 : create folder on save item in custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component

I've created a custom component in which my client can add and manage different accommodations. I would like to automatically create a folder (with name of Alias) inside '/images' whenever the client adds a new object (accommodation) to the component. I did find that I should be able to fire for example `JFolder::create` on `onContentAfterSave`, found a example of somebody using it to do the same in com_articles with use of a plugin, but somehow I cannot get it to work inside my custom component.

(To be complete: the issue here is that the mediamanager, when used in a subform like I do, does not show the option to create a folder. Hence I would like to add it this way).

Anyone any thoughts on this?

```
// code I have in edit.php of component

function onContentAfterSave(){
    $foldername = $accommodation->alias;

    // First we set up parameters
    $searchpath = JUri::root() . '/images/accommodations' . $foldername;

    // Joomla doesn't autoload JFile and JFolder
    JLoader::register('JFile', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/filesystem/file.php');
    JLoader::register('JFolder', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/filesystem/folder.php');

    // Then we create the subfolders
    if (!JFolder::create($searchpath . "/gallery"))
    {

    };
    if (!JFolder::create($searchpath . "/slider"))
    {

    };
};
```

Comment: It would help if we saw some code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be a little confused with `JUri::root()`. This method doesn't provide a path, but a URL.

So your current code:

```
$searchpath = JUri::root() . '/images/accommodations' . $foldername;
```

will output:

> http://example.com/images/accommodationsXXXXX

---

You'll need to make us of `JPATH_SITE`. So replace the above code with this:

```
$searchpath = JPATH_SITE . '/images/accommodations' . $foldername;
```

Hope this helps